# Code is given first chance exception in foreach loop C#

Tags: exception, nullreferenceexception

This is my code that is generating first chance exception but i think foreach loop first check the null reference before iterating then why a System. NullReferenceException ??

```
                HtmlNodeCollection nodes = crawledPage.HtmlDocument.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table");
                foreach (HtmlNode node in nodes)
                {
                    if (Regex.IsMatch(node.GetAttributeValue("class", ""), @"infobox(.)*"))
                    {
                            Program.con.Insert(crawledPage.ParentUri.AbsoluteUri, crawledPage.Uri.AbsoluteUri, node.OuterHtml);
                    }
                }
```

if anyone clairify i will appreciate

Comment: Where do you see the exception? What's the stack trace?

Comment: there occur first chance exception of system.nullreferenceexception and i set my debugger to break when this type of exception encountered so my program breaks and enter into debug mode and given extra information --- 
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: debugger points to the foreach loop line of code and my local variables have node object set to null

Comment: What is the stack trace?

Comment: theres no stack trace but the information i had already given above